# How to hide a panel if datetime field is empty

Tags: datetime, xpages

I have a computed field that display a datetime value from a document data source
    #{doc.LastEditedAt}

the computedField is surrounded with a panel, I want to hide the panel by setting the render property to false if the LastEditedAt field is empty, how to do that?

Comment: What have you already tried, Thomas? It sounds so easy so there must be a catch :-)

Comment: The catch is that you must go after the item in the document rather than the component in the panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Per's comment: this 'sounds' like a simple question, so I'll throw in a simple answer. How about setting rendered to:

```
#{javascript:doc.getFirstItem("LastEditedAt").getDateTimeValue() != null}
```

You might also want to extend that with a check to see if the field is available at all.